# Can I scan barcode scanner with smart phone camera using PHP/JS?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, barcode-scanner

Im actually about to start a project with barcode scanner using php/laravel and js only, is it possible to scan barcode using phone camera running in any browser.

thanks in advance

Comment: Most browsers give you the ability to request the user to allow your page access to the device's camera I think. It's likely to be platform / device / browser specific though, so you should research the level of support on different platforms. Broadly though this would be done using JavaScript. A fallback is to ask the user to upload a photo they have already taken

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942549/take-a-picture-with-mobile-using-javascript

Comment: Can I use node js package in my laravel ? I've seen a barcode scanner for node but i dont know if i can use that package to my laravel app.

Comment: Well node is a server side alternative to PHP/laravel, so not really... they are totally different languages. It's a non starter, unless the same code would work in a browser - browsers also run JavaScript if course (just like node), but the difference in environment might make some things not function. It depends on the specifics of the library...if it tries to access the device's camera it might be ok. If it is trying to read from some specific barcode scanning hardware then probably not, because browser code won't have access to that device on the user's machine